# Mathematics to self study

Tags: self-learning

I do not know if this is the right place for this question. I am an undergraduate math student entering his junior year this coming fall, but I'd like to teach myself some math that is accessible to me giving my current knowledge. So far I have taken (all undergraduate):

a linear algebra course, a theory of ODE/dynamical system's course, a topology course that went up to basic algebraic topology (Which I did not understand a lot), and Calculus 1-3.

Next semester I am taking real analysis, numerical analysis, and intro probability theory.

So in essence my question is what topics could I self study over this summer?

Comment: **Seeking personal advice:** Questions about choosing a course, academic program, career path, etc. are off-topic. Such questions should be directed to those employed by the institution in question, or other qualified individuals who know your specific circumstances.

Comment: I’d say read PMA (Principles of Mathematical Analysis).

Comment: I'd say some abstract algebra (you can check out Benedict Gross' lectures online), a second course in linear algebra or prepare for real analysis.

Comment: If you're interested in learning something outside of math: for computer science, I highly recommend working through all the projects in The Elements of Computing Systems by Nisan and Schocken. For physics, I got a whole lot out of reading some of The Feynman Lectures on Physics. For biology, Molecular Biology of the Cell is a great book. For pure Math, you might check out Visual Complex Analysis by Needham, Mathematics and Its History by Stillwell, Calculus by Spivak. For applied math, I like Introduction to Applied Math by Strang. Also Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe.